# JSON objects and HTML tables

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

First time poster here and new to JavaScript...

Below is my JSON object...

```
[  
   {  
      "Name":"Ted",
      "EmailAddress":"ted@ted.edu",
      "Title":"Director",
      "Expertise":"Statistics",
      "PhoneNumber":"444-444-4444"
   },
   {  
      "Name":"Ann",
      "EmailAddress":"ann@ann.edu",
      "Title":"Director",
      "Expertise":"Physics",
      "PhoneNumber":"444-444-5555"
   }
]
```

What I need is to be able to loop through this to add each table row for each employee. There are five values: Name, EmailAddress, Title, Expertise, PhoneNumber

This is what I have so far...

```
$(function () {
var Employees= [{"Name":"Ted","EmailAddress":"ted@ted.edu","Title":"Director","Expertise":"Statistics","PhoneNumber":"444-444-4444"}, {"Name":"Ann","EmailAddress":"ann@ann.edu","Title":"Director","Expertise":"Physics","PhoneNumber":"444-444-5555"}];

$("#pager").append("<table id='employeelist' class='table'><table>");

//for loop goes here//
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Also, how would I make the e-mail addresses 'clickable'/'mail to' the address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple loop will do, you should also build the entire HTML string, then append:

```
var table = "<table id='employeelist' class='table'>";
for (var i = 0; i < Employees.length; i++) {
    //Create the table row
    table += "<tr>";

    //Create table cells
    table += "<td>" + Employees[i].Name + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + Employees[i].EmailAddress + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + Employees[i].Title + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + Employees[i].Expertise + "</td>";
    table += "<td>" + Employees[i].PhoneNumber + "</td>";

    //Close table row
    table += "</tr>";
}
table += "</table>";
$("#pager").append(table);
```

Comment: Also- do you know how I would make the e-mail addresses 'mail to' the correct address?

Answer (score 0):

Since JSON objects are just normal Javascript objects, you can treat them as such.

For example, in order to loop over them you could just do normal Javascript loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Employees.length; i++) {
    var employee = Employees[i];
}
```

and then, in order to access information from an employee, you can just do `employee.Name` to access it's name, `employee.Title` for the title etc.

Using the information in employee.Name and the others, you can simply build your strings using that information:

```
str += '<td>' + employee.Name + ...
```

and then finally append it with `$("#pager").append(str);`.

Answer (score 0):

'Welcome to Stackoverflow and javascript :)'

It is actually a javascript object ( not JSON object ).

```js
$(function() {
  var Employees = [{
    "Name": "Ted",
    "EmailAddress": "ted@ted.edu",
    "Title": "Director",
    "Expertise": "Statistics",
    "PhoneNumber": "444-444-4444"
  }, {
    "Name": "Ann",
    "EmailAddress": "ann@ann.edu",
    "Title": "Director",
    "Expertise": "Physics",
    "PhoneNumber": "444-444-5555"
  }];

  var table = '<table id="employeelist" class="table">';
  for (var i = 0, j = Employees.length; i < j; i++) {
    table += '<tr>';
    table += '<td>' + Employees[i].Name + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + Employees[i].EmailAddress + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + Employees[i].Title + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + Employees[i].Expertise + '</td>';
    table += '<td>' + Employees[i].PhoneNumber + '</td>';
    table += '</tr>';

  }
  table += '</table>';

  $("#pager").append(table);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery. Then it should be something like this:

```
var table=$("<table>",{
   id:"employeelist"
}).addClass("table");
table.appendTo($("#pager"));
$("#pager").append(table);
$.each(Employees, function(index, employee){
    var row=$("<tr>",{});
    $("<td>",{
         html:employee.name
    }).appendTo(row);

 $("<td>",{
         html:employee.EmailAddress
 }).appendTo(row);
 $("<td>",{
         html:employee.Title
 }).appendTo(row);
 $("<td>",{
         html:employee.Expertise
 }).appendTo(row);
 $("<td>",{
         html:employee.PhoneNumber
 }).appendTo(row);
 row.appendTo(table);
});
```